# Flattening multidimensional table python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, flatten

Im a beginner in Python and Pandas and i want to transform a multidimensional table to a flattened one. It currently looks as follows

| Day | Lukas |  | Steve |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | BBnr | Comments | BBnr | Comments |
| 1 | XXXX1 | 2PM | XXXX3 | 9PM |
| 2 | XXXX2 | 5:30PM | XXXX4 | 7PM |

I want it to be like this:

| Day | Seller | BBnr | Comments |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Lukas | XXXX1 | 2PM |
| 1 | Steve | XXXXX3 | 9PM |
| 2 | Lukas | XXXX2 | 5:30PM |
| 2 | Steve | XXXXX4 | 7PM |

Any ideas? I tried it with pandas Melt and unstack so far but it didn't work out

This is my current code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('Book1.xlsx', sheet_name="Sheet1", header=[0,1], index_col=[0])

melt = df.melt()
print(melt)
```

And current output:

```
     Dag       NaN   value
0  LUCAS      BBnr   XXXX1
1  LUCAS      BBnr   XXXX2
2  LUCAS  Comments     2PM
3  LUCAS  Comments  5:30PM
4  STEVE      BBnr   XXXX3
5  STEVE      BBnr   XXXX4
6  STEVE  Comments     9Pm
7  STEVE  Comments     7PM
```

df.head() before the melt:

```
Dag  LUCAS           STEVE         
      BBnr Comments   BBnr Comments
1    XXXX1      2PM  XXXX3      9Pm
2    XXXX2   5:30PM  XXXX4      7PM
```

Comment: `.stack()`? Appart from that, which errors did you get? In principle `melt()` should work as well

Comment: @maow Hi, thanks for replying! I added the current code and output to the post!

Comment: Could you also print `df.head()` before the melt operation? I would like to try a few things :)

Comment: @maow added it aswell :) ty!!

Comment: I got the same answer as @Serge Ballesta :D The trick was to pass `level=0` to `stack` so that it melts only the names and keeps the colums BBnr and Comments intact

Comment: @maow many thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A trick is to *hide* in the index the columns that you do not want to process with `stack`.

Assuming that your dataframe is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({('Day', ''): {0: 1, 1: 2},
                             ('Lukas', 'BBnr'): {0: 'XXXX1', 1: 'XXXX2'}, 
                             ('Lukas', 'Comments'): {0: '2PM', 1: '5:30PM'},
                             ('Steve', 'BBnr'): {0: 'XXXX3', 1: 'XXXX4'},
                             ('Steve', 'Comments'): {0: '9PM', 1: '7PM'}}
```

it displays as you have shown as:

```
  Day  Lukas           Steve         
        BBnr Comments   BBnr Comments
0   1  XXXX1      2PM  XXXX3      9PM
1   2  XXXX2   5:30PM  XXXX4      7PM
```

It can be processed with:

```
result = df.set_index('Day').stack(level=0).reset_index()
```

Which directly gives:

```
   Day level_1   BBnr Comments
0    1   Lukas  XXXX1      2PM
1    1   Steve  XXXX3      9PM
2    2   Lukas  XXXX2   5:30PM
3    2   Steve  XXXX4      7PM
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! There is actually one little side note: the data is imported from excel so the dataframe is without dictionary. Im not too sure whether or not if that is a useful sidenote or a blunder. EDIT: found it, many thanks guys!!!!!